# Custom AuthorizeAttribute works on controller but not method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, methods, attributes, controller, authorization

I created a custom AuthorizeAttribute:

```
public AjaxAwareAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute {
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        if(filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult && filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Items["RequestWasNotAuthorized"] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

When I apply this to a Controller Class the OnAuthorization event is fired and the handler above is executed as expected but when it is applied to any method within a controller, nothing happens !?

Comment: It works on my machine. Are you sure the methods in the controller are hit? Are they reachable? Can you step through? I sure can.

Comment: Yes I have a break point set inside the controller method and it is being hit but the OnAuthorization method within the attribute is never executed. I should probably add that I am very sure this was working when I first coded it up. The code is from: http://trycatchfail.com/blog/post/Handling-Authorization-Failures-for-AJAX-Requests-in-ASPNET-MVC-Applications.aspx

Comment: did you register the attribute/validator classes in your app's bootstrapper or Global.asax ?

Comment: There is no need to register attributes as they are code added compile-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to give Robotsushi the credit here but he didn't respond with an Answer.

The real problem with my code was in the CustomFilterAttributeFilterProvider code.

```
protected override IEnumerable<FilterAttributes> GetActionAttributes(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) {

//incorrect code 
//var attributes = base.GetControllerAction(controllerContext, actionDescriptor);

//correct code
var attributes = base.GetActionAttributes(controllerContext, actionDescriptor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Robotsushi is on to something here!

I have the following in my bootstrapping code:

```
var oldProvider = FilterProviders.Providers.Single(f => f is FilterAttributeFilterProvider);
FilterProviders.Providers.Remove(oldProvider);

var newProvider = new CustomFilterAttributeFilterProvider(kernel);
FilterProviders.Providers.Add(newProvider);
```

This was code I added after adding the custom attribute. When I remove these lines of code then the attribute fires as expected.